# What is meaning of setting port number to NULL in document.domain call?

Tags: csrf, web, cors, same-origin-policy

Here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) it is mentioned

> The port number is checked separately by the browser. Any call to document.domain, including document.domain = document.domain, causes the port number to be overwritten with null. Therefore, one cannot make company.com:8080 talk to company.com by only setting document.domain = "company.com" in the first. It has to be set in both so their port numbers are both null

I am new to this and have a bit of confusion. What is the meaning of setting the port number to null? How are HTTP requests made then if the port is no longer 80/443?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481251/what-does-document-domain-document-domain-do/1525312#1525312

Comment: Since I do not have enough reputation to comment in StackOveflow, I am asking it here. Suppose I have 4 origins ['a.b.com', 'b.com', 'a.b.com:3000', 'b.com:3000'] and I set document.domain = 'b.com' in all of them, will the browser treat all four as same origin since the port is set to null for all of them?